# Lowest power WiFi module for IoT

Tags: wifi, esp8266

I have to select a WiFi chip for IoT device that basically has the following features:

- battery powered (non rechargeable)
- acquire sensors using I2C and analog lines every 5 minutes
- connect to an access point and send the data on a TCP socket (HTTP GET)

The battery should last at least for 150,000 connections.
I need to roughly estimate the capacity of such a battery...

All the peripherals (sensors, ADC, RF ecc...) are powered ONLY during the acquisition. Hence, during the stand-by, the power consumption is below few tens of uA.

The critical phases are of course connecting to the AP and transmit the data to the server. The devices should first check if the AP is available, otherwise they return to stand-by immediately. And if the AP is available it will be VERY close, so the transmitting power should be kept to the minimum.

Thus I'm looking for a WiFi chip/module which should have this (ideal characteristics):

- wide power supply range: 2.7V - 4.1V
- very fast power up and shutdown

What might change the time required to connect to the AP?

I'm reading through the documentation of [ESP-WROOM-02](http://espressif.com/en/products/hardware/esp-wroom-02/overview) but I'm wondering if there are more suitable modules for this application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at TI's [CC3200](http://www.ti.com/product/cc3200) which was the 1st generation chip and [CC3220](http://www.ti.com/product/cc3220) which is now the 2nd generation. This has an ARM Cortex M4 MCU and a network processor in a single chip. They have tons of sample code that you can use readily and it has features through which you can set power levels etc. there is a bit of a learning curve with this device though.

Comment: Good shot! I'm going to order the evalutation board. It seems to meet the requirements about power supply and the ev board has facilities to measure the current consumption of the *CC3200 chip only*.

Comment: Be sure to read through their documentation. Also if embedded C seems daunting you can use Energia to program the chip the same way you would an Arduino. Energia is an IDE made for specific TI processors and is based off the Arduino IDE. It has the same syntax as an Arduino.